# ASP.NET 5 roslyn dynamic compilation

Tags: c#, asp.net, roslyn, dnx, kestrel-http-server

I have simple `ASP.NET 5` Web Api Application, which was made using `yo aspnet`. I'm working on Windows 10 using Visual Studio Code (don't want to use Visual Studio). I want to simulate development from non Windows environment.

As I know `roslyn` compiler should dynamically compile changed files. But when I run my app with following command `dnu restore && dnx --watch web` application starts. But if I then (`dnx --watch web` is still running) change small part of code and refresh web page, noting is changed.

Before:

```
    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

After:

```
    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2", "value3" };
    }
```

I have check if this is cause of caching, but it is not. What am I missing here?

**NOTE:**

I have noticed that this could be cause of web server, I'm using `Kestrel`. There is part of my `project.json`

```
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  }
```

Comment: Just to make sure: have you actually saved the file?

Comment: Good question, yes I did :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have temporary solution to this problem, using [gulp.js](http://gulpjs.com/):

```
// gulpfile.js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var bg = require("gulp-bg");

var dnxweb = null;
gulp.task('dnx:web:start', dnxweb = bg("dnx", "web"));
gulp.task('dnx:web:stop', () => {
    if (!dnxweb)
        return;
    dnxweb.setCallback((proc) => {
        if (proc.errorcode != 0)
            proc.exit(proc.errorcode);
    });
    dnxweb.stop();
});

gulp.task('watch', () => {
    gulp.watch('**/*.cs', ['dnx:web:stop', 'dnx:web:start']);
});

gulp.task('build', ['dnx:web:start', 'watch']);
```